# Ember Data Multiple Stores

Tags: ember.js

So I'm just starting to learn ember js. In the case of the application rest api I have namespaced models.

example: `App.GlAccount = DS.Model.extend({})`

the route I need it to follow is /gl/account

I thought I could fix this by creating another store like 
   `App.GlStore = DS.Store.create({adapter:DS.RestAdapter({namespace:'gl'})}`

The problem is the model uses App.Store...Anyway to tell a model to use a different store?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example it doesn't sounds like you actually need to have multiple data stores. The following should be all you need:

```
App.GlAccount = DS.Model.extend({});
App.GlAccount.reopenClass({
  url: 'gl/account'
});
```

If your needs are more complex, it is possible to have per-type adapters for your data store. See this gist for details: https://gist.github.com/4004913

Comment: I tried the url parameter and it didn't work. I looked at the RESTAdapter code and it never checks it.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is both `namespace` and `plurals`, `namespace` will tell your store to use "gl" before "account" and `plurals` (IMHO should be renamed to something else) will tell your adapter to use a predefined string instead of letting the framework decide what's the url.. the way your model is set up, the framework will try to send requests to "yourdomain.com/gl_accounts" instead of "yourdomain.com/gl/account"