# Ember Data: use different store in routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an API that has objects at resource `/api/resource`. I can access that one with a `this.store.find(...)` call because I have set a namespace to `api` extending an Adapter.

Now I'd like to also access same resource, but this time under a `/admin/resource` URL. And I thought it would be the easiest to do with new adapter has a namespace `admin` instead of `api`.

Example:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.AdminAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/admin'
});

App.AdminStore = DS.Store.create({
  adapter: App.AdminAdapter
});
```

How can I now access an `AdminStore` in my routes?

I read [DS.Store documentation page](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) but example there isn't really clear to me. I will be happy to submit a pull request to docs when I figure it out how to use more than one store per app.

I know there is a [SO question with same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236594/ember-data-multiple-stores) but the answer isn't helping me.

Comment: Try looking up the Per Type Adapter so each resource could have a different adapter instance w/ different namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pixelhandler mentioned in comments I could use `Per Type Adapter`. I found documentation about it on `TRANSITION` document for `ember-data` [here](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters).

What I ended up doing was just specifying adapter for type with different namespace like so

```
App.AdminModelAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/admin'
});

App.AdminModel = DS.Model.extend({
  slug: DS.attr('string')
});
```